# plot_grid - Labels unreadable,

Tags: r, label, cowplot

I try to visualize non-normalized vs. normalized feature data in boxplots aligned next to each other with cowplot.
Features are 57 variables numbered incremental

```
plot_grid(
  sample_data1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(ID, outcome), names_to = "feature") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = feature, y = value, fill = outcome)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(legend.position="top"),
  
  sample_data1.norm %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(ID, outcome), names_to = "feature") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = feature, y = value, fill = outcome)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(legend.position="top"),

    label_size=3
)
```

However, the label_size does not have any effect [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gzrF.png), rows are way too small and labels are too small to be readable. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you provide sample....
Maybe `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))` will make font size of letters on y axis smaller.

Comment: Output example is posted.
That worked fo the label text size! Thanks
Any idea on how to change general height of a data point to make more space between the rows?

Comment: @Str1atum If you mean space betewwn points, use cex = @@ argument in geom_boxpoint() and to decrease width of boxplot, add witdh = @@ like geom_boxplot(width = ??) .